# How to run PHP Code from command line on linux Server

Tags: linux

How can i run PHP Code from command line on Linux Server.

I have code which is a PHP Code I need to run that On linux as a cronjob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use [PHP CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) to run your code.

Like

$php -q /var/www/code.php

and using crontab -l and crontab -e command you can setup cronjobs.

Answer (score 3):

**Run PHP code from command line on Linux:**

```
$php code.php
```

**Add PHP file to run as a cron job:**

```
$crontab -e
```

Add the schedule to cron.

Ex:

```
1 0 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/code.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```